# Determinant Evaluation

Tags: linear-algebra, determinants

Is there a closed form (something involving a ratio of products) for:

$$\det\left[\binom{a_i+c}{a_i-i+j}\right]_{1\leq i,j\leq t},$$

where $a_i,c$ are positive integers? I think with $c=0$ this is basically a LGV determinant but, with $c>0$ I'm not so sure.

Comment: Have you looked at Krattenthaler's papers on determinants?

Comment: @SteveHuntsman: I have, for example "A determinental evaluation and some enumeration results for plane partitions": http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.23.3644

It seems like this essentially counts plane-partitions bounded by $c$. In the paper it's mentioned that there's no known explicit formula in the general case but I'm wondering if these have been considered elsewhere? In the linked paper, Theorem 5 has something similar but by a  (intended) miracle, the calculation goes through.

Answer (score 2):

A general formula for free parameters $a_i$ does not seem feasible.

For the specialization $a_i=i$, the determinant has a nice closed form
$$\det\left[\binom{i+c+d}{c+i-j}\right]_{i,j=1}^t
=\prod_{k=0}^d\binom{t+c+k}c\binom{c+k}k^{-1}.$$

Comment: Note that this is $=\prod\limits_{k=0}^d\dfrac{k!(t+c+k)!}{(t+k)!(c+k)!}$. Is there any explanation of that surprising symmetry in $t$ and $c$?

Comment: BTW, where does your $d$ come from?

Comment: The $d$ is designed to make my proof work, which can be provided if need be.